# Loading calendar via Scriplets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use [scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) to load an embedded Google Calendar in an Apps script page, and I'm having mixed luck.

This is my HTML code with an 'iFrame' section. The scriplets in this code simply grab the users email, formats it by replacing the '@' symbol with a '%' so that it can be used to load the calendar, and then generates the embedded link and posts it to the page:

```
  <?var self = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var self = self.replace(/@/gi, "%");
  var url = "https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=" + self + "&ctz=Europe/Dublin";
  ?>
  <p><?= url?></p>

  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=<?= url?>&ctz=Europe/Dublin" id="myFrame" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Using the 'URL' in the iFrame loads the calendar successfully, but there's unwanted 'junk' text, as I'm embedding a URL within a URL. For some reason this works, however, the following do not:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=<?= self?>&ctz=Europe/Dublin" id="myFrame" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<iframe src=<?= url?> id="myFrame" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I would have expected either of these to work, and the original working one to fail. why, and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `var self = self.replace(/@/gi, "%40");` as %40 = @ using URL escape codes

Then the following should work(so make sure you have double quotes around the `url`):

```
<iframe src="<?= url?>" id="myFrame" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: So obvious, yet hours spent looking at it. This solved it, thanks.